# how to split the date of my datepicker date state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i have a date picker that work perfectly but i need the date splited, the normal output is something like this 12/16/1900, but i need to split this state into month = 12, day = 16 and year = 1900

any help would be apreciated

this is my datepicker code

```
    const [vBirthDate, setvBirthDate] = useState('');
    return ( 

<View style={styles.containerdate}>
                <DatePicker 
                  date={vBirthDate} //initial date from state
                  mode="date" //The enum of date, datetime and time
                  placeholder="select date"
                  format="DD/MM/YYYY"
                  minDate="01/01/1900"
                  maxDate="01/01/2019"
                  confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                  cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                  androidMode="spinner"
                  customStyles={{
                    placeholderText: {
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateIcon: {
                      height: 0,
                      width: 0,
                    },
                    dateText: {
                      color: '#b3b4b5',
                      fontSize: 16,
                    },
                    dateInput: {
                      borderWidth: 0,
                    }
                  }}
                  onDateChange={(date) => {setvBirthDate(date);console.log('algo');} }

                />
              </View>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split string with date to 3 variables like this:

```js
const date = "12/16/1900"
const [month, day, year] = date.split('/')
console.log(`Month: ${month}`)
console.log(`Day: ${day}`)
console.log(`Year: ${year}`)
```

Comment: srry for adding more troubles, but how can i use them? im trying to make a function that just imprint them but it just throw undefineds this is my function
    const RFC = () => {
      console.log(vName, 
        vSecondName, 
        vLastName, 
        vSecondLastName, 
        vBirthDate,
        month, vBirthDate.day, `Year: ${year}`);
    }

Comment: where is the date string saved?